# docker-machine cant connect to host/daemon and using insecure registry

Tags: macos, ubuntu, docker, ssl-certificate, docker-machine

So im having some weird problems with docker-machine. I am trying to set up a docker-machine on my Mac OS El Capitan and also have the daemon flagged for a few insecure registries. I was able to successfully push/pull on a local Ubuntu install (without docker-machine) by setting the DOCKER_OPTS options to flag my insecure Nexus docker registries. I am trying to accomplish the same end goal on my Mac OS. So far I have installed the Docker Toolbox using a default installation and have tried the following in Terminal.

```
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:~ Vinay$ sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox --
engine-insecure-registry mynexusrepo.cloudapp.net:18443 --engine-insecure-registry mynexusrepo.cloudapp.net:18444 --engine-insecure-registry mynexusrepo.cloudapp.net:18445 dev
Creating VirtualBox VM...
Creating SSH key...
Starting VirtualBox VM...
Starting VM...
To see how to connect Docker to this machine, run: docker-machine env dev
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:~ Vinay$ eval "$(sudo docker-machine env dev)"
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:~ Vinay$ sudo docker-machine ls
NAME   ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM
dev             virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376   
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:~ Vinay$ sudo docker pull mynexusrepo.cloudapp.net:18445/docker-thirdparty/mongodb:3.0.2
Password:
Post http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/images/create?fromImage=mynexusrepo.cloudapp.net%3A18445%2Fdocker-thirdparty%2Fmongodb%3A3.0.2: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:~ Vinay$ sudo docker images
Password:
Get http:///var/run/docker.sock/v1.20/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: no such file or directory.
* Are you trying to connect to a TLS-enabled daemon without TLS?
* Is your docker daemon up and running?
Vinays-MacBook-Pro:~ Vinay$ docker-machine -version
docker-machine version 0.4.1 (e2c88d6)
```

So I know the sudo docker pull mynexusrepo.cloudapp.net:18445/docker-thirdparty/mongodb:3.0.2 command works since it works fine on my straight Ubuntu OS with a docker install. Is there something else I am missing? I have tried closing all the terminals, deleting all of the docker-machines, restarting, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the main problem is that the docker-machine I created isnt becoming "active". I have done echo $DOCKER_HOST and it matches up with the tcp address from above. According to this that is all that is needed to make the machine "active".  https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/active/. 

So now im starting to think its a problem with the virtualbox driver. I will attempt to uninstall everything and try it again.